# Use nlohmann json to unpack list of integers to a std::vector<int>

Tags: c++, json, list, unpack, nlohmann-json

I'm using [nlohman::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

It's awesome, but is there any way to unpack:

```json
{
    "my_list" : [1,2,3]
}
```

into a `std:vector<int>` ?

I can't find any mention in the docs, and `std::vector<int> v = j["my_list"];` fails, as does `j["my_list"].get<std::vector<int>>()`.

*Crosslinking to https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1460*

Comment: it seems you have to do that by hand iterating on xx.items() to push_back the element into the vector ( https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_afe3e137ace692efa08590d8df40f58dd.html#afe3e137ace692efa08590d8df40f58dd )

Comment: or using from_json to an intermediate std::array ? not easy to read their sources (https://nlohmann.github.io/json/json_8hpp_source.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually it *does* work. I had not isolated a test case, and my JSON string was malformed.

So,

```
json J(json_string);
J["my_list"].get<std::vector<int>>()
```

***does*** work.

In my case I make sure my C++ variable names match the JSON keys, so I can simply use the macro:

```cpp
#define EXTRACT(x) x = J[#x].get< decltype(x) >()

int foo;
std::vector<float> bar;

EXTRACT(foo);
EXTRACT(bar);
```

Comment: I still have an runtime error, I'm curious what you did to fix it...